WW2 submarine movie where they eject a crewman via a torpedo tube as a ruse
There was a war movie about a u-boat trapped below the surface and it contains a scene where the commander forces a sick man to be fired from a torpedo tube to fool the enemy above.
What was the name of the film?

Oh...and none of the movies would ever show a sick person put through a torpedo tube while still alive. There have been movie instances of bodies being used that way...you might be misremembering.

Could this be U-571 (2000)? Although this trope has been used on multiple occasions (including real life, I believe), this film spends a considerable amount of time agonising over the decision to jettison a dead crewman.



You may also recall some controversy at the film having so many glaring inaccuracies.
